# Tumour in a nutrient rich environment.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

In a laboratory experiment, a small spherical tumour of radius $a$ composed of living cells is immersed in a large, nutrient-rich water bath.

Inside the tumour, the concentration satisifies the equation

$0= −k +\frac1{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}(r^2 \frac{dc}{dr})$.

In the bath, the concentration satisfies the equation

$0= \frac1{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}(r^2 \frac{dc}{dr})$ in a ≤ r < ∞.

The nutrient flux at the tumour surface $r = a$ is continuous so that
$\frac {dc}{dr}\vert_{r=a^-} = \frac {dc}{dr}\vert_{r=a^+}$

In the far-field the condition $c → c_0$ as $r → ∞$ applies, for constant $c_0$.

(a) Write down a condition on c to be satisfied at $r = a$.

(b) Find the solution for the nutrient concentration in 0 ≤ r ≤ a and a ≤ r < ∞.

(c) Cells die if $c < \hat c$ for a constant threshold value $\hat c$ . Obtain a condition on the
tumour size a for a necrotic core to develop.

I am very new to tumour models, I understand the general idea is to integrate to find $c(r)$ and apply boundary conditions, but given my lack of understanding of the science behind it (the maths I'm fine with), I am struggling to come up with suitable boundary conditions to solve this. This is a past exam question I found online.

Comment: Solve the equation for outside the tumour, using the boundary condition at $\infty$.  Use that to find out what $c$ and $dc/dr$ must be at $r = a$.

Comment: Thank you so much this was a huge help! Have you got any suggestions for part c?

Comment: Presumably, the solution inside the tumour decreases as $r$ gets smaller (you'll have to check this). If so, you just need to find the value of $a$ that gives $c(0) = \hat c$. Larger $a$ will give smaller values of $c(0)$ meaning the tissue dies from lack of nourishment. For smaller $a$, $c(0)$ should be larger, meaning the tissue does not die.

Comment: Perfect Thanks!

Comment: Actually, something seems to be missing here. Solving the two equations for $c$ each requires two integrations, resulting in 4 constants of integration that need identified. The condition as $r \to \infty$ provides a value for one constant, and the continuity of both $c$ and $c'$ at $r = a$ provides two more equations. reducing this from 4 degrees of freedom to 1. But I don't see anything more that would remove that last degree of freedom and provide a specific function $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my last comment, $$\frac1{r^2}\frac d{dr}\left(r^2 \frac{dc}{dr}\right) = 0$$ gives
$$c = C - \frac Ar$$
and 
$$\frac1{r^2}\frac d{dr}\left(r^2 \frac{dc}{dr}\right) = k$$
gives
$$c = D  - \frac Br + \frac k{2r^2}$$
for some constants $A, B, C, D$. $c \to c_0$ as $r\to \infty$ yields $C = c_0$, and assuming $c$ is both continuous (presumably the answer to part (a)) and has continuous derivative yields
$$D = c_0 + \dfrac k{2a^2}$$ and $$B = A + \frac ka$$

which gives
$$c(r) = \begin{cases} \dfrac {c_0r - A}r + k\dfrac {r^2 - 2ar + a^2}{2a^2r^2},&r < a\\\dfrac {c_0r - A}r,& r\ge a\end{cases}$$

Regardless of the value chosen for $A$, this function meets all the conditions of the problem. Thus we do not know what $A$ is. The best that can be done for the rest of the problem is to solve it in terms of $A$.